# Method from WCF service not showing up in client app

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

My latest venture in C# coding is learning about WCF services. I'm attempting to make a very simple service. It has one method that isn't default and it simply returns a string of a user inputted integer multiplied by two. I've uploaded the service to aspspider.com, and have created a winforms client app. However when looking through the service class it only shows the GetData method. I'm honestly puzzled by this, and can't understand for the life of me why my method won't show up. I've used the svcutil.exe command from the command line and still nothing. If someone could help me out I'd really appreciate it! Here's my code:

Service Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace WcfService1
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {        
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        public string GetDouble(int value) //Method that isn't showing up
        {
            return (value * 2).ToString();
        }
     }
  }
```

Service Interface:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace WcfService1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        public string GetDouble(int value); //Method that isn't showing up

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }   
}
```

Service1Client(Note this is messy. Still trying to figure out how to format code on here):

```
namespace WcfService1
{
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="CompositeType", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService1")]
    public partial class CompositeType : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
    {
        private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;
        private bool BoolValueField;
        private string StringValueField;

        public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
        {
            get
            {
                return this.extensionDataField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.extensionDataField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get
            {
                return this.BoolValueField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.BoolValueField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get
            {
                return this.StringValueField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.StringValueField = value;
            }
        }
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="IService1")]
public interface IService1
{
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataResponse")]
    string GetData(int value);
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataUsingDataContract", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataUsingDataContractResponse")]
    WcfService1.CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(WcfService1.CompositeType composite);
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public interface IService1Channel : IService1, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel
{
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class Service1Client : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<IService1>, IService1
{
    public Service1Client()
    {
    }

    public Service1Client(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName)
    {
    }

    public Service1Client(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public Service1Client(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public Service1Client(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return base.Channel.GetData(value);
    }

    public WcfService1.CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(WcfService1.CompositeType composite)
    {
        return base.Channel.GetDataUsingDataContract(composite);
    }
}
```

Client:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WebServiceTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Service1Client client = new Service1Client();
            client.Open();
            label1.Text = client.GetData(5);
            client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where have you defined `Service1Client`? You have only posted code for the class called `Service1`.

Comment: I'll post that code now. Sorry!

Comment: Did you happen to deploy your service initially with just the GetData method? Given what others have noticed, it does look like your latest version isn't available to the client.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is this even compiling correctly? Interfaces can't declare visibility of methods in them. They are implicitly public. So, this;

```
[OperationContract]
public string GetDouble(int value);
```

Should be this;

```
[OperationContract]
string GetDouble(int value);
```

Comment: Didn't see that. It didn't seem to make a difference either way.

Comment: If there was no difference, then it sounds like your service module is not being built/compiled. So, the new method will not show up regardless of what you do to it.

Comment: @ZackMatthews - depends what the reason is and how you are deploying your components. I can't guess at that.

Comment: I'm just uploading the new .svc + .dll files whenever I revise it. Is there a different way I should be publishing?

Comment: The version you posted wouldn't even have compiled, so there is a problem somewhere in your process that meant you didn't even notice that. Perhaps recompiled DLLs are not being deployed to a build folder prior to you  publishing them.

Comment: I honestly don't really know what that means. Is there something I can try?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem. Apparently I forgot to compile the changes. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

So remove the access modifier from the Operation contract as shown below,

```
string GetData(int value)
{
    return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
}
string GetDouble(int value) 
{
    return (value * 2).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got your answer because of doing(Build and compile) in right direction. it may also happen somewhere if you are not opening solution in proper way.